# VBA Add-In can't reference Worksheet on Auto-Open

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel add-in and I want it to run certain macros whenever a template is opened. This runs fine if I open excel and then run the auto_open sub manually but throws 'Run-Time Error 9. Subscript out of range' when opening excel.

It seems like the add in is loading and trying to run before the template has loaded so that when trying to reference a specific sheet in the workbook it fails to find anything.

Specifically the error comes at

```
Set shtData = Workbooks("Example_Template.xlsm").Worksheets("Test")
```

How can I force the auto_open macro to run once the worksheets are loaded?

My auto open code is:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
   Set clsAppEvents = New clsApplicationEvents

   Application.Run "PerformanceOpen"

End Sub
```

And the macro I am trying to run contains:

```
Private Sub PerformanceOpen()

Dim shtData As Worksheet

Set shtData = Workbooks("Example_Template.xlsm").Worksheets("Test")
shtData.Activate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I force the auto_open macro to run once the worksheets are
>   loaded?

You cannot. The `Auto_Open` macro is specifically intended to run as soon as Excel starts, before any workbooks are available.

The code in PerformanceOpen needs to be placed in a Workbook_Open event. It can either be the Open event of a specific workbook, or you could study [cpearson's page](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx) about Application Level Events. This would allow you to run code when *any* workbook is opened, or a new workbook is added.

Comment: Okay thanks - can I make it the open event of a specific workbook while keeping the code in the add-in rather than the workbook itself? If so how would I go about it?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, you could write code that would run when *any* workbook is opened, then check the name of the book. I would question your approach though. An add-in is intended to add additional functionality to Excel. If it is waiting for another specific workbook to be opened then IMO it is no longer an add-in. Good luck ;)

Comment: Yeah I would obviously have preferred to just keep it as a simple workbook macro but for reasons out of my control it will only work in an add-in... Thanks for the help!